# Error thrown from Future.wait() is not caught in a try-catch block

Tags: dart, async-await

I am failing to understand, why the error thrown from `addItem` method in below code is not caught in the try-catch block

```dart
void main() async {
  var executor = Executor();
  var stream = Stream.fromIterable([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);
  try {
    await for (var _ in stream) {
      executor.submit(() => demoMethod());
    }
    await executor.execute();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}

Future<void> demoMethod() async {
  var list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5];
  var executor = Executor();
  var test = Test();

  for (var element in list) {
    executor.submit(() => test.addItem(element));
  }

  await executor.execute();
  test.list.forEach(print);
}

class Test {
  var list = <int>[];

  Future<void> addItem(int i) async {
    if (list.contains(i)) {
      throw Exception('Item exists');
    }
    list.add(i);
  }
}

class Executor {
  final List<Future<void>> _futures = [];
  bool _disposed = false;

  void submit(Future<void> Function() computation) {
    if (!_disposed) {
      _futures.add(computation());
    } else {
      throw Exception('Executor is already disposed');
    }
  }

  Future<void> execute() async {
    await Future.wait(_futures, eagerError: true);
    _disposed = true;
  }
}
```

but below code is able to catch the error properly

```dart
void main() async {
  var executor = Executor();
  try {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      executor.submit(() => demoMethod());
    }
    await executor.execute();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

I am guessing it has something to do with the stream processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the stream.

In your other examples, you synchronously run through a loop a and call `Executor.submit` with all the computations, then immediately call `executor.execute()`.
There is no asychronous gap between calling the function which returns a future, and `Future.wait` starting to wait for that future.

In the stream code, each stream events starts an asynchronous computation by calling `Executor.submit`. That creates a future, stores it in a list, and goes back to waiting for the stream.

If that future completes, with an error, before the stream ends and `Future.wait` gets called, then there is no error handler attached to the future yet. The error is then considered unhandled, and is reported to the current `Zone`'s uncaught error handler. Here that's the root zone, which means it's a global uncaught error, which may crash your entire program.

You need to make sure the future doesn't consider its error unhandled.
The easiest way to do that is to change `submit` to:

```dart
  void submit(Future<void> Function() computation) {
    if (!_disposed) {
      _futures.add(computation()..ignore());
    } else {
      throw StateError('Executor is already disposed');
    }
  }
```

The `..ignore()` tells the future that it's OK to not have an error handler.
You know, because the code will later come back and call `executor.execute`, that any errors will still be reported, so it should be safe to just postpone them a little. That's what `Future.ignore` is for.

(Also changed `Exception` to `StateError`, because that's what you should use to report people using objects that have been disposed or otherwise decommissioned.)